# How to understand quotes in command-substitution which surrounded by double-quotes in Bash?

Tags: bash

```sh
$ a=33
$ echo "$(echo '$a')"    # (1)
$a
$ echo "$(echo "$a")"    # (2)
33
```

I can't understand the shell command-line parsing result above.

For command line (1), according to `man bash`, single quote inside the double-quotes will be parsed as literal, and `$a` inside the double quotes will be interpolated, so I think the result of command line (1) should be `'33'`.

Comment: `$( )` creates a new quoting context. This means what's inside it is parsed independently of what's outside of it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thanks, `man bash` said: **The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion**. According to this: variable-expansion precedes command-substitution. so, i don't know why `$( )` will create a new quoting context? can you share some references about this for me?

Comment: I don't know of a completely explicit statement of this, but according to the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), "With the $(*command*) form, all characters following the open parenthesis to the matching closing parenthesis constitute the *command*. Any valid shell script can be used for *command*, except a script consisting solely of redirections which produces unspecified results." This seems to imply that `echo '$a'` does the same thing when it's in `$( )` that it does on its own, with no exception for outer quotes.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have single-quotes in double-quotes. `$(....)` is a command substitution. Essentially what occurs within `(...)` takes place within its own subshell. You must employ quoting rules within that subshell. The subshell represents its own environment.

For example:

```sh
$ a=33
$ echo $(echo "'$a'")    # single-quotes within double-quotes
```

The quoting rules within the command substitution are applied correctly resulting in the output:

```
$ '33'
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks. `echo "$(echo '$a')"`, why `$a` did't interpolate when parsing the outer double-quotes, `man bash` said: parameter-expansion is parsed before command-substitution. so, `You must employ quoting rules within that subshell. The subshell represents its own environment`, isn't the parameter-expansion of `$a` done before entering the command-substitution subshell?

Comment: Because when single-quoted variable expansion is suppressed. Single-quotes in double-quotes lose their special meaning for preventing variable expansion.

Comment: I am very confused about this. Please let me show you how I understand `echo "$(echo '$a')"`.  
1. The bash interpreter read the command line what i typed.   
2. the bash interpreter parse the command line:  
- first, it finds a left `"`, so it read the subsequent chars  until it finds the right double-quote,   
- then, parse the contents inside the `""`, such as variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution...at the same time, single quotes in the `""` treated as literials.

Comment: So, In my opinion, `echo "$(echo '$a')"` will become `echo "$(echo '33')"` after variable expansion, and then become `echo "33"` after command subsitution, and the final result is be `33`.

Comment: When you have `echo "$(echo '$a')"`, your command substitution is `echo '$a'`where you have `$a` enclosed in single-quotes. Single quotes alone prevent variable expansion. So `'$a'` is treated as a literal `'\$\a'` and the variable `a` is never expanded to provide its value. When you use single-quotes within double-quotes `echo "'$a'"` the single quotes no longer prevent variable expansion and are just treated as part of the string. `"'$a'"` so the `'` is printed as a literal character and `$a` is expanded and replaced by its value.

Comment: See [man 1 bash - QUOTING](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) (about 1/10th of the way down)

Comment: Thanks a lot. In fact, I have read this doc several times, maybe my understanding about **QUOTEING** in man bash is wrong, so i can't find the answer in man bash and the result puzzled me.I know how to write right commands when using quotes, but i don't know command substitution will have its own quoting-context.